# Weird case for relative velocities and special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, velocity

This has bothered me for a while. I've been taught that the formula for determining the perceived velocity on an object from another moving object's reference frame under special relativity is:

$$v = \frac{w - u}{1 - wu/c^2}.$$

If two objects travel from earth at $c$ in exactly opposite directions, what is the perceived velocity of one from the other? The formula seems to give a divide by zero error.

Comment: First, massive object do not more at $c$ relative anything and secondly no time passes for massless objects so the question is ill-defined.

Comment: To confusedLayman: For the "objects" you're thinking about to travel at $c$, they will have to be massless. For example, photons.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7446/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11398/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget to use signs. In your example, $w$ is, say, $c$, then $u=-c$. Hence
$$v = \frac{w - u}{1 - wu/c^2} = \frac{2c}{2} = c$$

as expected.

Comment: Damn, I looked at the question for a couple of minutes without seeing the sign difference in the velocities :-)

Answer (score 0):

> If two objects travel from earth at c in exactly opposite directions,
>   what is the perceived velocity of one from the other?

The relativistic velocity addition formula cannot be applied in this case.  As you write, if an object has speed $w$ in one frame and you want to know the object's speed in another frame moving with relative speed *u*, then you would use the relativistic velocity addition formula.

But, **there is no reference frame moving with speed *c* relative to another reference frame**.

If there are two objects moving away from Earth with speed $c$ in opposite directions, **then each object has speed $c$ in all reference frames.**

That is to say, **there is no reference frame in which either object is at rest**.

Let's look at your question again:

> what is the perceived velocity of one from the other?

More precisely, your question is  *"what is the speed of one of the objects **in a reference frame in which the other is at rest**"*.

*But there is no reference frame in which either object is at rest.*

So, the question is ill posed; it presumes the impossible - that there is a frame of reference in which either object is at rest.