# Distance Between Two Photons Calculated in Different Inertial Frames

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

I am a self-studier. This is a question from a text I am studying:

> The distance between two photons traveling along the $x$-axis of an inertial frame, $S$, is always $l$. Show that in a second inertial frame, $S'$, moving at constant speed $V = \beta c$ along the $x$-axis, the separation between them is given by:
>   $$\Delta x' = l\left(\frac{1 + \beta}{1 - \beta}\right)^{1/2}$$

I would appreciate help solving this. I was also wondering what $l$ is in the frame of the photons.

Also I was wondering how to deal with the length $l$ in the $S$ frame, as it seems to be moving at the speed of light.

Thanks for your help and patience with an enthusiastic beginner.

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried and what you think the relevant concepts are? Such questions are usually closed without such information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't normally answer homework question in full, but I'll answer because I'm very eager to make the point that the best, by far, method of answering questions like this is to choose relevant spacetime points in $S$, apply the Lorentz transformations and find where the points are in $S'$. This normally makes the answer obvious.

In this case we have a pair of photons travelling along in $S$ with a distance of $\ell$ between them. Let's choose our $x$ axis so that the photons are travelling along it, and we'll choose the origin so that in $S$ the rear photon is at the point $(t = 0, x = 0)$. This means that at time zero the front photon is at $(0, \ell)$:

[image: Photons]

All we have to do is find the two points in $S'$, and work out the spacing between them and we'll have our answer. The [Lorentz transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation) are:

$$ t' = \gamma (t - \frac{vx}{c^2}) $$

$$ x' = \gamma (x - vt) $$

If we feed in the first point $(t = 0, x = 0)$ we just get $(0, 0)$, so in $S'$ the rear photon is at the origin. If we feed in the position of the front photon $(0, \ell)$ we get:

$$ t' = \gamma (t - \frac{vx}{c^2}) = -\gamma\frac{v\ell}{c^2} $$

$$ x' = \gamma (x - vt) = \gamma\ell $$

So in $S'$ the front photon is at $(-\gamma\frac{v\ell}{c^2}, \gamma\ell)$. But we don't want to know the position of the front photon at time $t' = -\gamma\frac{v\ell}{c^2}$, we want to know it at time $t' = 0$. So we wait a time $-\gamma\frac{v\ell}{c^2}$ during which the photon (travelling at $c$) moves a distance $c\gamma\frac{v\ell}{c^2} = \gamma\frac{v\ell}{c}$. So at time zero in $S'$ the position of the front photon is:

$$ \left(0, \gamma\ell + \gamma\frac{v\ell}{c}\right) $$

and the spatial separation between the two points is just the $x'$ coordinate of the front photon:

$$ \ell' = \gamma\ell + \gamma\frac{v\ell}{c} \tag{1} $$

The rest is just algebra. The question defines $\beta = \frac{v}{c}$, and the Lorentz factor $\gamma$ is then given by:

$$ \gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \beta^2}} $$

Substitute this into equation (1) and we get:

$$\begin{align}
 \ell' &= \ell\left( \frac{1 + \beta}{\sqrt{1 - \beta^2}} \right) \\
       &= \ell\left( \frac{1 + \beta}{\sqrt{(1 - \beta)(1 + \beta)}} \right) \\
       &= \ell\left( \frac{\sqrt{1 + \beta}}{\sqrt{1 - \beta}} \right) \\
       &= \ell\left( \frac{1 + \beta}{1 - \beta}\right)^{\tfrac{1}{2}}
\end{align}$$

Which is what we were asked to prove.

Comment: Dear John, Thanks for such a generous, instructive answer. I know this looks like homework, but I am 69 year-old, and started self-studying a few months ago. So without help such as this, I am lost in space-time. I spent a lot of time fiddling with the $x'$ equation, but never would have thought to use the $t'$ as you did. Even seeing it, the $0$ mapping to a minus quantity elicits some delightful thinking. With regards,

Comment: @Andrew: You're welcome :-) About 35 years ago my physics tutor instructed me most severely to **always** reach for the Lorentz transforms when solving problems in SP. I have spent the 35 years since passing this on :-)

Answer (score 0):

First consider what you're transforming. The $\Delta x$ interval is $l$ while the $\Delta t$ interval is $l/c$ (if you can't see why draw a [space-time diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_diagram#Basics)). The interval $l$ in the $S$ frame is simply the distance between two points. It's easy to picture if you imagine them as stationary particles, and easy to picture if they're moving slowly. It holds that the interval is the same even when the points are travelling at the speed of light. The speed only changes the time interval, which is made easier to see with a space-time diagram (try drawing up all three cases!).

Now you can use the Lorentz transformation:
$$
\Delta x' = \gamma(\Delta x -v\Delta t)
$$

And simplify to get the answer in the correct form.

Further, the idea of $l$ in the frame of the photons is not possible. This is because photons do not have a rest frame. Since one of the fundamental principles of special relativity state that light speed is constant in all inertial reference frames, there cannot exist a frame where the speed of a photon is zero; it *must* be $c$. Hope that clears some things up for you.

Comment: Nuclear_Wizard: "_imagine them as stationary particles_" -- +1 for matching Einstein's ["_space-time propositions amount to the determination of space-time coincidences {such as} encounters between two or more recognizable material points_"](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Foundation_of_the_Generalised_Theory_of_Relativity#ch.3.p.776). "_photons do not have a rest frame._" -- [Right.](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/104333) But: "_light speed is constant in all reference frames_" -- No: in **inertial** frames. Finally: "_even when the points are travelling at the speed of light._" -- -1.

Comment: @user12262, yes I should say inertial frames. Although I am unsure what your point is about "even when the points are travelling at the speed of light." I was trying to say that it is fine for an interval to move at c. Is that not clear? (or correct?)

Comment: Nuclear_Wizard: "_it's fine for an interval to move at c_" -- An interval moving?? A pair of events moving?? Anyways, my main objection was against the OP's question itself speaking of "`distance between photons`" (I blame the text being studied; not the messenger(s).) Distance is between "_[pairs of] points [as pairs of] stationary particles_" you considered; but not "_even when the points are travelling at the speed of light._" Now: "_[...] constant in all inertial reference frames, there cannot exist a frame where the speed of a photon is zero_" -- Why not some "**non**-inertial frame"?!?

Answer (score 0):

I have been thinking more about this problem. Of course, my understanding of the application of Lorentz transformations was substantially enhanced by the two answers kindly provided.

I was able to solve it using proper time.

Also, due to the nature of the problem, I can solve it using just the time equation of Lorentz transformations:

$t' = \gamma (t - \frac{vx}{c^2})$. In this case, $t'= \frac{\ell'}{c}$.

Then $\frac{\ell'}{c} = \gamma (\frac{\ell}{c} - \frac{v\ell}{c^2})$

The rest follows as in (1) in the first of the answers above.