# Speed of Light and Relative Velocity

Tags: special-relativity, velocity, faster-than-light

Yesterday I was going through the idea of Relative Velocity in which, when the bodies are moving in opposite directions, their velocities add up. So, if one of the bodies in consideration is light, would the velocities still add up? If yes, then won't it break the ultimate speed limit, the speed of light?

It would be great if you explain it using math that's not too advanced, I'm only 14

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(Almost) double light speed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11398/)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/11402/191954

Answer (score 1):

To make it simpler, if two objects are moving towards each other, the speed of one object with respect to another is (if they are moving on the same axis or line):

```
u=(v+u')/(1+(v*u')/(c*c)) (in Newtonian case v+u' which makes sense)
```

where u is speed of one object with respect to another
v speed of one of the object with respect to inertial frame of reference
u' speed of the other object with respect to inertial frame of reference

so now assume that one of the objects is light, so that v = c

which makes
            u=(c+u')/(1+(c*u')/(c*c))

```
        u=(c+u')/(1+(u'/c) (c/c makes 1)

        u=c*((1+u'/c)/(1+u'/c)) = c
```

If you still have some difficulties in understanding, you can ask me, maybe I missed to explain something which makes it harder to understand

Comment: So even if one of the objects moving in opposite direction is c, the relative velocity will still remain as c.