# Special Relativity and Light

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, velocity, faster-than-light

I just started learning about relativity in my physics class and would like some help understanding the concepts.

My question is imagine two objects start emitting light and are 1 lightyear away from each other. If the moment they start emitting light they start moving away from each other in opposite directions, each traveling at 0.6c, will the light emitted from each object ever reach the other since the relative speed would be 1.2c? And if the light does reach the other object, will it take the light more than one year to traverse the distance?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11398/2451 and links therein.