# If a photon travelled in the opposite direction of another photon

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, velocity, faster-than-light

If a photon travels in the opposite direction as another photon, then what is the speed of the second photon **relative to the first**. Is it 2 times the speed of light? Also what if two photons travelled on the same direction?

If you answer please include an explanation with formulas if possible which is also easy to understand.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11398/2451 and links therein.

Comment: 2 photons with antiparallel $\vec k$ always move apart at $2c$ in all reference frames. According to the photons: that is not a question, there are no reference frames at $c$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula can be applied to two objects heading away from each other at *nearly* the speed of light.